# Devise Omniauth, how to link google account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I've set up devise to work with omniauth and. This is how devise.rb looks like:

```
...
  config.omniauth :facebook, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, :scope => FACEBOOK_APP_PERMISSIONS
  config.omniauth :openid, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'yahoo', :identifier => 'yahoo.com'
  config.omniauth :openid, OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'gmail', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
...
```

I want to link an existing account with the the above 3, with the following code from the callback controller:

```
...
  def callback(provider)
    if utilizator_signed_in?
      # link it's account
      if Login.link_omniauth(current_utilizator, omniauth_data)
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.link.success", :kind => provider
        redirect_to :root
      end
    else
      utilizator = Login.auth_with_omniauth(omniauth_data)

      if !utilizator.nil?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => provider
        sign_in_and_redirect utilizator, :event => :authentication
      else
        utilizator = Login.register_omniauth(omniauth_data)
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.register.success", :kind => provider
        sign_in_and_redirect utilizator, :event => :authentication
      end
    end
  end
...
```

It works just great with facebook, but for google and yahoo the current user get's signed out and a new user is created.

How can I skip the user sign_out phase ?

Thank you,

Edit:
 I am using the latest version 3.0.rc3.
 The functions from Login are easy to guess:
 link_omniauth - will link the current logged user to a account
 auth_with_omniauth - will auth the user
 register_omniauth - will register a new user

The problem here is that utilizator_signed_in? (user_signed_in?) will return false for google when the user is signed in, I think there is a prior sign_out happening that is not happening for facebook.

Comment: What version of omniauth are you using? Maybe you should show the output of the functions you use in the Login Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to my question.
This guy https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/185 had the same issue.

Thanks for your replies,

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend this tutorial: [here](http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/11) (far more in-depth than the rails casts and other tutorials on the topic). In particular, it has a comprehensive 200 line piece of code (`services_controller.rb`) to create the controller that you will need to handle any authentication service (Twitter/Facebook/Google/Github) efficiently using Omniauth, and either link it to pre-existing Devise accounts, or create new accounts.

I have a (almost) live project running with that [here](http://www.eyekandy.in) -
You can sign in using Facebook/Twitter (I haven't enabled google/github for now), and if you go to Profile->Services after you are signed in, it will show you the multiple authentication services linked to your account.

I'm reluctant to upload my project's source since it has a lot of other code that isn't relevant to this at all, but if you really feel like you need it, then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope already submit my gmail address link to my profile task into my application